# Error in Details link of MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating a Forum in asp.net MVC3 it contains link of Details which on click will show me details of particular record, but I am getting the following error when I click on the Details link.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in
>   'Prjct_name.Controllers.DefaultController'. An optional parameter must
>   be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Since I'm very new to MVC dont know how to deal with this

Comment: Can you display what code you are using to render the link, and what the resulting HTML for the link actually is? The href is probably missing a placeholder for id

Answer (score 1):

Still you want to use this URL [www.mydomain.com/Default/Details] you can set id as nullbale in controller :

```
  public ActionResult Details(int? id)
   {
        if (id ==null)
          { 
          // Do stuff
          } 
        else
          { // Do something else
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your ActionResult looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Which would require the url be something like www.mydomain.com/Default/Details/1 where 1 is the id of the item but the url you are hitting is www.mydomain.com/Default/Details without the /[id].  In MVC, if one of your ActionResult prameters is 'id', that parameter is expected to be in the url...not the querystring.